# Xcode, iOS, "Stop "(null)", "An instance of "(null)" is already running..."

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 7.2.1, iOS 9.2.1, ARC enabled

Sometimes when I am quickly building and running a project in Xcode back to back I get this error:

[image]

Xcode still thinks that it is still running an instance of my application on the device, however, the application has long since been terminated.

When I click "Stop" it just hangs up and looks like this...

[image]

I have tried waiting for 5 minutes, but the error does not clear and the status does not update to indicate that the application stopped running.

The only solution is to restart Xcode.  This ends up being a huge hassle, because I have to navigate back to where I was and open all the necessary windows again.

Does anyone have an alternative way of handling this error?

It seems to occur when I intermix using the stop button with using the short cut to run the project (⌘ + R).

Much thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 2/23/2016**

I noticed that when I unplug and plug the cable back in after the error occurs the project allows a new build and instance to run, but the old instance never goes away, so you end up with multiple "running" projects.

Does anyone know how to get rid of that?  Or add to the original solution?

Comment: This has happened to me a couple of times, and the best solution I found is just unplug the device and plug it into de computer again after 5 seconds. This could help you avoid the hassle of closing Xcode.

Comment: Thanks!  Let me try that next time the error occurs.

Comment: Yup that seems to work thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st Solution :**

> Technique 1- Clean your project , and then build.
>
> Technique 2- Quit your Xcode, Clear your derived Data , plug In you
>   Data Cable Again , Then Run your Project.

**2nd Solution (Happened For me too) :**

> Change Your Data Cable.

Comment: Thanks!  Let me try that next time the error occurs.

Comment: Unplugging and plugging the device back in works!  Thank you.